# Adoptable storage missing on "Samsung Galaxy Tab A" after partitioning the SD card

Tags: samsung, partitions, adoptable-storage

I have a [Samsung Galaxy Tab A (8"-2019)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OaifV.png). I tried to partition my 128 GB, **Kingston**, MicroSD card into 75% internal (adopted) and 25% external.

[image: Before adopting]

The partition command, for ID = 179,64; was as follows:

```
sm partition disk:179,64 mixed 25
```

After reboot, I realized that the **adopted/internal** part (should be, approximately, 96 GB) part is **missing**, and that the external one is shown.

[image: After adopting: MicroSD card partitioned BUT adopted/internal missing!]

The whole process is shown through [the Windows PowerShell below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3AUYn.png):

```
K:\> adb devices
List of devices attached
R9WN91B9GYJ     device
K:\> adb shell
gto:/ $ sm list-disks
disk:179,64
gto:/ $ sm partition disk:179,64 mixed 25
gto:/ $ reboot
K:\>
```

Afterwards, I executed the following command:

```
adb shell sm list-volumes all
```

and here is the [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPrLt.png) (I cannot implement it):

```
K:\> adb devices
List of devices attached
R9WN91B9GYJ     device
K:\> adb shell
gto:/ $ sm list-disks disk: 179,64
gto:/ $ sm list-volumes all
private: 179,67 mounted d8ef1b16-ab2b-4010-a1b1-79b1cc6cff16
private mounted null
emulated;0 mounted null
public:179,65 mounted 3484-15EF
emulated:179,67;0 unmounted null
gto:/$ sm list-volume all
usage: sm list-disks [adoptable]
       sm list-volumes [public|private|emulated|stub|all]
       sm has-adoptable
       sm get-primary-storage-uuid
       sm set-force-adoptable [on|off|default]
       sm set-virtual-disk [true|false]

       sm partition DISK [public|private|mixed] [ratio]
       sm mount VOLUME
       sm unmount VOLUME
       sm format VOLUME
       sm benchmark VOLUME
       sm idle-maint [run|abort]

       sm fstrim

       sm forget [UUID|all]

       sm set-emulate-fbe [true|false]

       sm set-isolated-storage [on|off|default]

       sm start-checkpoint <num-retries>

       sm supports-checkpoint

gto:/ $
```

- Where is the **adopted/internal** storage?
- Is there something **wrong**?
- Is there a way to **fix** it?
- Is there a way to **undo** partitioning using **ADB commands**?